# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql, php7

Hola tengo un problema con una condicional if cuando pongo como condición

```
if ($pagina > $total_paginas || $pagina <= 0) {
    header('Location:index.php?pagina=1');
 }
```

la cantidad de filas son 7 de mysql 
almacenada en $total_paginas y la variable $pagina
vale 1, entonces si el usuario pone 8 en la url `pagina=8` me redirecciona a
`index.php?pagina=1` perfecto!! ahora cuando pongo en la url `pagina=0` me sale este error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

-.- les dejo todo el código debajo...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Paginación</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php 
     include_once "includes/bdd.php";
         
     $con = openCon('includes/databases.ini');

     $con -> set_charset('utf8');

     $por_pagina = 5;
     
     if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {

      $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

     }
     else {
      $pagina = 1;
     }

     $empieza = ($pagina - 1 ) * $por_pagina;

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios LIMIT $empieza, $por_pagina";

     $resultado = $con -> query($sql);

  ?>

  <div class="container">
  <h2>Lista De Correo</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>País</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <?php 
      while ($fila = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $fila['nombre'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $fila['email'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $fila['pais'] ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      }
       ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
     <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

     $resultado = $con -> query($sql);

     $total_registros = $resultado -> num_rows;

     $total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);
     

     /*ERROR NO TOMA EN CUENTA $PAGINA <= 0 SOLAMENTE!!!*/
     if ($pagina > $total_paginas || $pagina <= 0) {
       header('Location:index.php?pagina=1');
      }


     ?>
   <!-- Paginacion -->
   <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina <= 1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>">
      Anterior
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php 
     for ($i = 0; $i < $total_paginas; $i++) { 
     ?>
     <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina == $i + 1 ? 'active' : '' ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i + 1 ?>">
        <?php echo $i + 1 ?> 
      </a>
     </li>
    
     <?php 
      }
      ?>
     <li class="page-item <?php echo $pagina >= $total_paginas? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
      <a class="page-link" href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">
      Siguiente
      </a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Fin paginación -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```